# How to connect to elastic search from Azure Databricks nootebook?

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

How to connect & write dataframe to elastic search from Azure Databrick notebook using scala or python?

Is elastic search can be connected via JDBC connection, if yes, how?

Tried out below:

```
df_latest_data = spark.sql("select * from deltastream2.deltatable")
df_latest_data.write.write.format(
    'org.elasticsearch.spark.sql'
).option(
    'es.nodes', 'http://spark.es.amazonaws.com'
).option(
    'es.port', 9200
).option(
    'es.resource', '%s/%s' % ('index_name', 'doc_type_name'),
).save()
```

Exception:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o233968.save.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
Failed to find data source: org.elasticsearch.spark.sql. Please find packages at
http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
       
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.failedToFindDataSourceError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:557)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:758)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSourceV2(DataSource.scala:808)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.lookupV2Provider(DataFrameWriter.scala:983)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:258)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1195.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.DefaultSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$5(DataSource.scala:744)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$4(DataSource.scala:744)
    at scala.util.Failure.orElse(Try.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:744)
    ... 14 more
```

Searched out missing package but not found,

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o233968.save.: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: org.elasticsearch.spark.sql. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html

I also tried to reproduce and got silmilar error:
[image]

The above error you are facing because of the data source `org.elasticsearch.spark.sql` was not found or required library is not properly installed.

**To inastall library:**

- Go to the **Libraries** tab of that cluster, and click **Install new** -> choose **Maven** -> enter the maven coordinates `elasticsearch-spark` -> click **Install**.
  [image]

**library is installed:**
[image]

Now, try again.